# How do I show P(Z = z) if Z = X+Y, both random discrete variables.

Tags: probability

If Z = X+Y, and both are random discrete variables.

How do I show

[image]

Comment: Here's the idea: Fix some $x$. We want $x+y=z$, so we know that $y= z-x$. Now sum over all $x$ the probability $P(X=x, Y=z-x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs just two steps:

1. split up into cases according to the possible values of $X$. (Whenever the goal formula involves a sum indexed by the values of $X$, you can guess this is probably involved.)
2. then notice that the condition “$X = x$ and $Z = x$” is equivalent to “$X = x$ and $Y = z-x$”.
   $$
   \begin{align*}
   P(Z=z) & = \sum_x P(X=x\ \text{and}\ Z=z) \\
   &= \sum_x P(X = x\ \text{and}\ Y = z-x)
   \end{align*}
   $$

Comment: Thank you. This is precisely where I was with it but it seemed a little too simple. Wonderful.

Comment: Also, do you need to change Y=x-z to Y=z-x?

Comment: @DanielMack: thanks for the typo catch — edited to fix!  And generally — never be too worried by a proof turning out simple.  Many proofs *are* simple when done the right way — the difficulty is usually in finding that right way to do them.